# Magento 2 : How to check if we are on a search result page?

Tags: magento2.2.6, search-result

Is there a way to check that we are on search result page in Magento 2?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: if you are checking for just testing you can try this ` $this->getRequest()->getFullActionName();` if you are at `catalogsearch_result_index` it means you are at search result page

Comment: Thanks buddy, its working for me.

Comment: welcome Happy Coding :)

Comment: Waqar Ali, please post this as answer

Comment: @AmitBera i have Posted Answer you can check now

Comment: I have upvoted your answer, thanks for help

Comment: @PurushotamSharma Accept my answer if it worked for you

Answer (score 4):

if you are checking for just testing you can try this

```
echo $this->getRequest()->getFullActionName();
```

if you are at

> catalogsearch_result_index

it means you are at search result page

Answer (score 1):

In .phtml try with below code :

`print_r($this->getRequest()->getFullActionName());`

if you get return like :  `catalogsearch_result_index`

That is you are at search result page.